# Tuples print element if condition else print another value in range

Tags: python, tuples

I have 2 lists, 1 is nested. I want to export this to txt with a conditional. Each different letter starts with... i.e.: "Letter,A" and followed by the third element of its tuple exists, otherwise print a ",". The condition of existence is if the second element of the tuple is in range with the `var` (from 0 to 5):

```
var=5

letter=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
nested_list=[
('A', 1, 0),
('A', 2, 0),
('B', 1, 9),
('B', 3, 9),
('C', 2, 0),
('C', 4, 0),
('C', 5, 0),
('D', 2, 9),
('E', 3, 0),
('F', 3, 9)]
```

My Code so far:

```
bd="Letter,"

for i in range(0,len(nested_list)-1):
    if nested_list[i][0]!=nested_list[i+1][0]:
        bd+="\nLetter,%s,"%(nested_list[i][0])
        for j in range(0,var):
            if nested_list[i][1]==j:
                bd+="%s,"%nested_list[i][2]
            else:
                bd+=","
    elif nested_list[i][0]==nested_list[i+1][0]:
        bd+="\n"
        for j in range(0,var):
            if nested_list[i+1][1]==j:
                bd+="%s,"%nested_list[i+1][2]
            else:
                bd+=","

print bd
```

Current Output:

```
Letter,A,,,0,,,
Letter,A,,,0,,,B,,,,9,,
Letter,B,,,,9,,C,,,,,0,C,,,,,,
Letter,C,,,,,,
Letter,D,,,9,,,
Letter,E,,,,0,,
```

Expected Output

```
Letter,A,0,0,,,
Letter,B,9,,9,,
Letter,C,,0,,0,0
Letter,D,,9,,,
Letter,E,,,0,,
Letter,F,,,0,,
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is always ordered correctly, I think this is a great use-case for itertools.groupby:

```
In [14]: from itertools import groupby

In [15]: from operator import itemgetter

In [16]: for k, group in groupby(nested_list, itemgetter(0)):
    ...:     plist = ['']*5
    ...:     for _, idx, val in group:
    ...:         plist[idx-1] = str(val)
    ...:     print("Letter,{},{}".format(k, ','.join(plist)))
    ...:
Letter,A,0,0,,,
Letter,B,9,,9,,
Letter,C,,0,,0,0
Letter,D,,9,,,
Letter,E,,,0,,
Letter,F,,,9,,
```